# How to access content of dom-if inside a custom element?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

In a custom element I want to access a `span` and append a child to it but all usual accessors give `undefined`:

```
<template>
    <template is="dom-if" if="[[condition]]" restamp>
        <span id="myspan"></span>
    </template>
</template>

 ready() {
   var a = this.$.myspan;                     //<------- is undefined
   var b = this.$$.myspan;                    //<------- is undefined
   var c = document.getElementById("myspan"); //<------- is undefined
   var d = this.$$("#myspan");                //<------- is undefined
}
```

How to access a `span` in this case?

UPDATE: here is [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/cU3RK0)

Comment: The last one should work when `condition` is `true`, when `condition` is `false` none will work.

Comment: @Günter Zöchbauer, doesn't work, here is a proof: http://plnkr.co/edit/cU3RK0

Comment: Seems Polymer needs some additional time to process `dom-if`. This works `this.async(function () {console.log('this.$$("#myspan")',this.$$("#myspan"));});
` (same as in Flavio Ochoa's answer).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason this didn't work inside the lifecycle callback without setTimeout or this.async is that right after attaching your element the dom-if template has not yet rendered. Upon attaching your element, Polymer calls the attached callback. However, when the value gets set on the the dom-if, an observer runs and debounces its own _render function. The debounce waits an amount of time to catch any other calls to it, and then it executes the ._render function and attaches the element to the DOM. In other words, when the attached callback runs, normally the dom-if template hasn't rendered yet.

The reason for this debounce is performance. If several changes were made within a very short span of time, this debounce prevents the template from rendering several times when the result we would care about is the end result.

**Fortunately, dom-if provides a .render() method which allows you to make it render synchronously.** All you need to do is add an id to your dom-if, switch to an attached callback and call like this:

```
<template>
    <template id="someDomIf" is="dom-if" if="[[condition]]" restamp>
        <span id="myspan"></span>
    </template>
</template>

 attached() {
   this.$.someDomIf.render();
   var c = document.getElementById("myspan"); //<------- should be defined
   var d = this.$$("#myspan");                //<------- should be defined
}
```

Triggering a synchronous render on the dom-if shouldn't be a huge performance problem, since luckily your element should only be getting attached once.
**Edit:** As it turns it, this *even* works in a ready callback:

```
<template>
    <template id="someDomIf" is="dom-if" if="[[condition]]" restamp>
        <span id="myspan"></span>
    </template>
</template>

 ready() {
   this.$.someDomIf.render();
   var c = document.getElementById("myspan"); //<------- should be defined
   var d = this.$$("#myspan");                //<------- should be defined
}
```

See this fork of your plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/u3richtnt4COpEfx1CSN?p=preview

Comment: according to the following conversation this.$.someDomIf.render(); doesn't guarantees that myspan element is ready....    https://github.com/Polymer/docs/issues/1456

Comment: @3141526 That's not what they're discussing. They're discussing the issue you encountered without using .render(); The local dom gets initialized before ready under normal circumstances, but that doesn't mean that the dom-if has rendered it's children yet. This is the purpose of the .render() call: to render the template synchronously instead of asynchronously, to ensure it's rendered when you needed.

Comment: `this.$.someDomIf.render();` only renders if and only if the condition is truthy

Comment: @HariPrasad correct. If the condition is falsey, then there is nothing to render.

Answer (score 2):

Try to do it asynchronously in the attached method as follows, this method works:

```
attached: function(){
   this.async(function(){
     var d = this.$$("#myspan"); 
     console.log(d); 
   },someTimeIfThereAreManyItemsToLoad);
}
```

Comment: that works even without someTimeIfThereAreManyItemsToLoad. Any ideas why it doesn't work in ready(). And how to be sure that this.$$("#myspan") will always work even if "there are many items to load"

Comment: @31415926 See my answer below. There is a way to do it in an attached callback without using this.async.

Comment: This answer is incredibly hackish? What if I'm running on a 486 machine (so to speak)? I think @Dogs seems to be on the right track - however I haven't done much testing on whether `.render()` is truly synchronous.

Comment: @zerodevx based on the dom-if source, it should be. https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/blob/master/src/lib/template/dom-if.html

Answer (score 0):

The responses above only work if your condition is true initially. Please see my answer to your initial question that lead to this one : 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34137955/3085985

Not sure if you should mix in the .render-stuff from Dogs, but I still think the observer would be the right place for it as it otherwise does not work if condition is false initially.

Answer (score 0):

As in Polymer documentation:

> Note: Nodes created dynamically using data binding (including those in  `dom-repeat` and `dom-if` templates) are not added to the `this.$` hash. The hash includes only statically created local DOM nodes (that is, the nodes defined in the element’s outermost template).

You will need to use `this.$$('#yourElementId");`