# is it possible nest/inner dom-if where the second dom-if depends on value oberseved from the first dom-if block

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, dom-if

I read carefully these threads

[Polymer 1 nested dom-if within dom-repeat not updating when data changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34262747/polymer-1-nested-dom-if-within-dom-repeat-not-updating-when-data-changes)

[how to dynamically append an element to dom-if in Polymer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34137859/how-to-dynamically-append-an-element-to-dom-if-in-polymer/34137955#34137955)

[How to access content of dom-if inside a custom element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34138718/how-to-access-content-of-dom-if-inside-a-custom-element)

that may have some relation with my question but I didn't manage find any clue if I can do what I want and how.

In my company, there are several flows, each one for each business flow and each step of the flow is a screen coded as a Polymer 1 web component. All them are warraped in a root Polymer component which defines the route.

A simple exemple would be:

```
my-root-component:

<dom-module id="my-root-component">
    <template>
        <first-obrigatiory-page which-route={aValueReturnedFromFirstComponent}></first-obrigatiory-page>
        <template is="dom-if" if="[[_isTrueFunction(aValueReturnedFromFirstComponent)]]" restamp>
            <second-page which-sub-route={aValueReturnedFromSecondComponent}></second-page>
            <template is="dom-if" if="[[_isTrueFunction(aValueReturnedFromSecondComponentComponent)]]" restamp>
                <third-page ></third-page>
            </template>
        </template>
    </template>

        <script>
        Polymer({
            is: 'my-root-component',
            behaviors: [doesntMatterHere],
            properties: {
```

The first dom-if works as expected but the second seems not be taken in account and my third-page component is never showed.

I checked and the equivalent for _isTrueFunction(aValueReturnedFromSecondComponentComponent) is returning true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does `aValueReturnedFromFirstComponent` really return anything, because you should declare the attribute as `which-route="{{aValueReturnedFromFirstComponent}}"` instead of using simple `{ }`.

Does the `whichRoute` (note the camelCase) property in the `first-obrigatiory-page` element have the `notify: true` property so the variable actually sends back the updated value?

---

I usually set observers on variables whenever dom-ifs don't update so I can see if they really change or not, and then set the variables myself through the console with `document.querySelector('my-root-component').set('aValueReturnedFromFirstComponent', true)` so I can see that the dom-if really updates.

A workaround could be to use events, but what you've done should work.